# small ggplot object (1 mb) turns into 7 gigabyte .Rdata object when saved

Tags: r, ggplot2, save

I have a series of ggplot objects that I'm trying to save to an .rdata file to load into a Markdown document later. The ggplot object itself is quite small (a few KB). But, when I try to save the object as an .rdata file for later retrieval, the resulting .rdata file is now over 8 gigabytes. I've tried saving the plot directly from the GUI, saving as an .rds... Saving as a .pdf or other image results in a normal image of a few KB.

I'm stumped, has anyone else encountered this problem?

Sample workflow below, I can't provide reproducible code for the problem since I can't upload the dataframe required to make this plot

```
mcmsy<- (ggplot(data = subset(MonteCarlo, Policy == 'RBFM' & 
Year == BaselineYear), aes(MSY), alpha = 0.8) + geom_density(fill = 'steelblue2'))

object.size(mcmsy)

save(mcmsy, file = 'mcmsy_plot.rdata')
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about attempting to help you without a reproducible example.

Comment: ggplot makes copies of input data, especially when `stat_`'s are used. we really need to see `MonteCarlo`. also this is not reproducible with `movies` example in `stat_density`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm narrowing in on the problem. The "mcmsy" object is generated inside a function. The environment inside that function has several dataframes that are several gigabytes in size. Those objects aren't involved in mcmsy in any way shape or form. When I remove those large objects from the environment, generate mcmsy, and then save, the problem goes away. So, it appears that ggplot is saving data from the entire environment that mcmsy was generated in?

Comment: Take a look at `pryr::object_size` (and its documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon this problem as well. This is indeed related to the environment. If you want to save your plots as an `Rdata` file, then you should be creating a new environment inside the function that is generating your plot, so that the complete environment doesn't get saved. Example:

```
makePlot <- function(plot.data){
  env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
  env$subset <- plot.data

  my.plot <- with(env, {
    my.plot <- ggplot(subset, ...) 
    return(my.plot)
  })

  return(my.plot)
}
```

Comment: The above code does not seem to work, please see below:

Comment: The makePlot function should be modified to use the "subset" variable -- not the plot.data variable, which is not available inside the "with" i.e. my.plot <- ggplot(subset, ...) [otherwise, you will get the following error: object 'plot.data' not found when you run the function]