# RDS file size difference between ggplot2 objects created inside vs. outside function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build an R project that generates multiple ggplot2 objects using functions. However, I noticed that, when saving these objects as RDS files, the file sizes are much larger than I expected. I realized that saving an RDS object generated with a function, and the same plot in the global environment, give two very different file sizes, despite occupying equivalent memory in the R session. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1e6))

p1 <- ggplot(data) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = x))

plot_fun <- function(y) {
  p <- ggplot(y) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x = x))
  return(p)
}

p2 <- plot_fun(data)

object.size(p1) # 8 Mb
object.size(p2) # 8 Mb

saveRDS(p1, "plot1.rds")
saveRDS(p2, "plot2.rds")

file.info("plot1.rds", "plot2.rds")
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Am I returning the object incorrectly from the function?

Comment: See the solution proposed here (with code correction in the comments) for plots. It should also work for this case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192298/small-ggplot-object-1-mb-turns-into-7-gigabyte-rdata-object-when-saved/57315001#57315001

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one is tricky.  My initial advice was to use `pryr::object_size()`, which is more thorough about including the size of objects stored in the environment of an object, but that shows only a tiny difference between the two `ggplot` objects.

However, `ggplot` objects *contain* an environment, the `$plot_env` component, the contents of which will get stored along with the object.

The environment of `p2$plot_env` is that corresponding to the *inside* of your function:

```
ls(p2$plot_env)
# [1] "p" "y"
```

while the environment of `p1$plot_env` is the *global environment*, which contains a copy of the data as well as the other plot object ...

```
ls(p1$plot_env)
# [1] "data"     "p1"       "p2"       "plot_fun"
```

But this still seems a bit mysterious to me. `p1` (with more objects in its environment) creates the *smaller* file size (7.4M), while `p2` (with fewer objects) creates the *larger* file size (22M), and `p1` naively seems to have more stuff stored:

```
sapply(p1$plot_env,object.size)
## plot_fun       p1       p2     data 
##     6568  8004632  8004632  8000728 
sapply(p2$plot_env,object.size)
##       p       y 
## 8004632 8000728
```

Is this some kind of recursive nightmare where environments are referencing other environments, which all have to get stored? As @Chris says:

> `p2`'s environment has a parent environment of the global environment, while `p1`'s environment is the global environment...I imag[in]e what is happening is that, when R needs to serialize an environment that inherits from another env (i.e., a parent env), it saves the parent env along with the child. That would explain why saving `p1` would result in a smaller file size as compared to `p2`

If I replace the plotting environment of `p2` with the global environment, the file size does get smaller ... and I *think* I didn't break the plotting object.

```
p2$plot_env <- p1$plot_env
saveRDS(p2, "plot2.rds")
system("ls -lht plot?.rds")
## -rw-r--r--  1 bolker  staff   7.4M 15 Jun 20:15 plot2.rds
## -rw-r--r--  1 bolker  staff   7.4M 15 Jun 20:14 plot1.rds
```

If your workflow allows it, you might consider storing rendered versions of these plots (as PDF/SVG/whatever) rather than the plot objects themselves ... although the plot objects are certainly more flexible.

Comment: Hey Ben, `p2`'s environment has a parent environment of the global environment, while `p1`'s environment is the global environment...I image what is happening is that, when R needs to serialize an environment that inherits from another env (i.e., a parent env), it saves the parent env along with the child. That would explain why saving `p1` would result in a smaller file size as compared to `p2`.

Comment: yep, looks like you're on it!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am mostly trying to migrate my code into a drake-managed workflow, which advises storing outputs as objects, rather than as file outputs. I think this makes sense, as I will eventually like to incorporate these plots in markdown docs as well as rendered graphics files, and retain flexibility to adjust plotting parameters. Based on what you and Chris mentioned, I think I can fix this by setting a NULL environment when calling ggplot: ggplot(y, environment = NULL). This seems to do the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: the only concern would be that you could conceivably break a plot that depends on something in its environment - don't know when this would happen

Comment: Correction: the environment = NULL doesn't work in all cases; removing unneeded objects from the function environment before creating the plot object does help, though.

Comment: @BenBolker good point; just have to make sure everything in the call to ggplot is contained in data supplied to the function, or if removing objects, that I don't get rid of something important.

Comment: Regarding saving rendered versions of the plots, is there a way to do that within the rds, rather than saving an image to a separate file than the rds? E.g. A simplified plot object that is basically an image, with a print method that prints the plots panel.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get an accurate size for your object, use:
`length(serialize(p1,NULL))`.
As stated above, this difference comes from the environments.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for coming to this question 4 years late - it's been very useful to me today while trying to work out what some code of mine is doing.

I think I can add something on the difference between the size of `p1` and `p2`. I think `p1` is smaller *specifically because the environment is* `GlobalEnv`:

- When the plotting code is wrapped in a function, the function environment is a newly created environment, and `plot_env` seems to store its entire contents.
- However, when it is not, the environment is just `GlobalEnv`, and in this case `plot_env` seems to store just a reference to `GlobalEnv`.

See an example to illustrate this here:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a plot inside a function ============================
test_plot <- function(a, b = 2){
  dat <- data.frame("a" = a, "b" = b)
  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point()
  return(p)
}
p_function <- test_plot(a = c(45, 46))
saveRDS(p_function, "plot_function.RDS")

# Create the same plot in the GlobalEnv ==================
a <- c(45, 46)
b <- 2
dat <- data.frame("a" = a, "b" = b)
p_free <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_point()
saveRDS(p_free, "plot_free.RDS")

# Now read them back in =================================
p_function_read <- readRDS("plot_function.RDS")
p_free_read <- readRDS("plot_free.RDS")

# Examine their environments ===========================
print(names(p_function_read$plot_env))
print(names(p_free_read$plot_env))
# Note that p_free, p_free_read and p_function_read are all in the environment for p_free_read
# That seems weird, given they weren't even around when this plot was made!

# If we clear the environment, what happens?
rm(list = ls())
p_function_read <- readRDS("plot_function.RDS")
print(names(p_function_read$plot_env))

rm(list = ls())
p_free_read <- readRDS("plot_free.RDS")
print(names(p_free_read$plot_env))

# So p_function_read still has everything in its environment from before. But p_free_read has only itself.

# We can further check by adding something fresh to the global environment
hello <- 3
print(names(p_free_read$plot_env))
```

Do correct me where needed - I'm very new to working with environments at all. Really this should be a comment on the above, but I don't have enough reputation for that...

Answer (score 0):

Investigating the ggplot2 object with the help of `length(serialize(x,NULL))` I found large environment data in several locations, removing them reduces the RDS file size and from what I can tell does not negatively affect the saved object. With `x` as my ggplot2 plot that used color mapping when making the plot, I did this:

```
x$plot_env <- globalenv()
attr(x$mapping$x, ".Environment") <- globalenv()
attr(x$mapping$y, ".Environment") <- globalenv()
attr(x$mapping$colour, ".Environment") <- globalenv()
attr(x$layers[[1]]$computed_mapping$x, ".Environment") <- globalenv()
attr(x$layers[[1]]$computed_mapping$y, ".Environment") <- globalenv()
attr(x$layers[[1]]$computed_mapping$colour, ".Environment") <- globalenv()
```

You may have to repeat for other elements if you have additional or different mapping variables.