# How to `dput` a `ggplot` object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to save some `ggplot` objects for later use. The `dput` function creates a string that when passed to `dget()` would return the errors of unexpected `<`:

- The first one is here: `.internal.selfref = <`. This can be easily solved by setting `.internal.selfref` to `NULL`.
- The remaining *seven* are distributed across different attributes, with the arguments being `<environment>`. I tried to change the `<environment>`'s to something like `NULL` or `environment()`, but none of them works - the environment is not set right and the object not found error is returned.

Some searches led me to the function `ggedit::dput.ggedit`. But it gives me the error:

```
# Error in sprintf("%s = %s", item, y) : 
#   invalid type of argument[2]: 'symbol'
```

I am thinking, either I set the environments right in using the `dput` function, or I figure out why `ggedit::dput.ggedit` does not work...

Any idea?

Comment: You can save it as a `.rds` with `saveRDS()`

Comment: Just a note, I would rather save the input data for ggplot (not ggplot object). Then in case, ggplot library gets upgraded/downgraded your saved object might fail to print, or you get a new data input to plot, then it is better to have the data and the script to re-run.

Comment: Can you add some info to the question regarding "why" you want to save the ggplot object with dput? To get from data to final visual chart (assuming you've assigned your ggplot2 object to a variable named  `gg`) it does `ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(gg))`. You should look at the `str()` for each of those esp the initial `gg`. This — https://rud.is/books/creating-ggplot2-extensions/demystifying-ggplot2.html — shows them for you. 1 thing that may be causing the giant size for the RDS is 1 element of the original `gg` is `$ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv>` (so that comes along for the ride.

Comment: The various object structures (even the `gg`) change with each ggplot2 version so as @zx8754 noted it's "unsafe" to rely on a serialized version of that structure over time. If you _really_ want to "serialize" it into one file, `dput()` your final data and put that + the ggplot2 plot commands into on R file.

Comment: @hrbrmstr please add your comments as answer. It is not what OP wants, but needs.

Comment: @hrbrmstr In fact, I have a really `big.dt`, and I am making plotssss out of it. To make each plot, quite some subsetting, binning, calculation, summary etc. of `big.dt` have to be done, before the resultant, smaller, oragnized `dt`(s) is(are) (Some plots uses more than one resultant `dt`) passed to `ggplot()` for graph plotting. As we are experimenting with the plotting and graphics, sometimes we would like to add/modify certain layers of the `gg` to optimize the visual, **without having to re-summarize the data (long time!) again**. So we want to save them, and take our time to play around.

Comment: So, then save off each summarised version of the object you pass into a ggplot2 plot build chain as an RDS and **read that in** right before the call to `ggplot()`. This is a common thing. I pull **lots** (I mean, you used bold for no reason so I figure it's en vogue) of data from Athena and Drill and do this exact same thing to great effect. I think you don't realize that ggplot2 **carries the data with it** (I have to point that out since you didn't bother to read the link i posted).

Comment: Yes. I agree that saving the results of all the wrangling before the ggplot call to `.rds` files is the best solution given the workflow you describe. And those `.rds` won't contain environments, so they will be small and quick to save.

Answer (score 2):

Not using `dput()`, but to save your ggplot objects for later use, you could save them as `.rds` files (just like any R objects).

Example:

```
my_plot <- ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))

saveRDS(my_plot, "my_plot.rds")
```

And to restore your object in another session, another script, etc.

```
my_plot <- readRDS("my_plot.rds")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but... when I `dput` my `ggplot` it is just done instantaneously with a file size of 45kb, but when I `saveRDS` the same `ggplot` it takes minutes with a file size of 1.8Gb! What is happening...? I have thousands of plots and this is certainly not doing the job...

Comment: Maybe have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883853/rds-file-size-difference-between-ggplot2-objects-created-inside-vs-outside-func

Comment: Maybe try to replace the plotting environment by the global environment as they suggest? 1.8Gb does seem very big though...

Comment: I don't know what your workflow looks like, but maybe another option could be not to save the plots and to source the script that produces your plots when you need them later?

Comment: Need some time to figure that out... maybe your last comment would be the best workaround for the moment. But I am interested in understanding more.

Comment: The post about the plot environment (my link above) might also help you figure out what is not working when you use `dput()`

Comment: Yet another option could be to create all your ggplot objects and save your entire environment in a `.rda`. But you would have to tread very carefully with that one to make sure you aren't messing something up by importing that environment later on. So that is probably the worst option to consider only as a very last resource. Not sure also how big that file would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse`

Save the plot beside the data in a tibble using `nest` and `map`.

```
library(tidyverse)

res <- mtcars %>% 
  as.tibble() %>%   
  nest() %>%  
  mutate(res=map(data, ~ggplot(.,aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()))
```

Then save the data.frame using `save` or `saveRDS`. 
Finally, call the plot:

```
res$res
```

[image]

The size is 4kb for tibble(mtcars) vs. 21kb with plot.

Comment: It is `as_tibble()` (all the tidyverse functions use snake case)

Comment: I don't care. `as.tibble` and `as_tibble` are identically; both call the same method. Use whatever you want.